# How do I view a Tree list of Schemas for a database in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle

How do I view the schemas, that belong to a database in SQL Developer? I am trying to get a view similar to Toad. In that you have the database name at the parent level, all the schemas below it which are then expandable to view all the objects that belong to that particular schema.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Expand the "Other Users" node.

Comment: brilliant answer!

Answer (score 34):

Two steps :

- Right click on the connection you have created
- Choose option Schema Browser to get the view of all schema in the drop down list along with the tables.

Comment: This way is nice in that it is more familiar with Toad's Schema Browser. Thanks.